# A question related to Novikov's condition

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-calculus

The well-known 'Novikov condition' says:

Let $ L = (L_t)_{t \geq 0} $ be a continuous local martingale null at 0 and $ Z = \exp(L - \frac{1}{2} \langle L \rangle) $ its stochastic exponential.

If

$ E[\exp(\frac{1}{2} \langle L \rangle_\infty)]  \ < + \infty $,

then $ Z $ is a (uniformly integrable) martingale on $ [0, +\infty] $.

Now to my question:

Is it also true that in this case $ Z_\infty >  0, P-a.s. $?

I'm interested in this question, because 
$ Z_\infty  > 0 $ would ensure that the measure $ Q $ defined by $ Q[A] := E_P [Z_\infty 1_A] $ is equivalent to $ P$.

Thanks for your help!
Regards, Si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because $\mathbb E [L_{\infty},L_{\infty}] < \infty$ will make L an $\mathbb L^2$ bounded martingale, so $L_{\infty}$ is finite (and the limit of $L_t$.)

Comment: Aha, do you mean something like: $ \mathbb{E}[\exp(\frac{1}{2} \langle L \rangle_\infty] < + \infty $ and $ \exp(x) \geq 1 + x $ imply $ \mathbb{E}[\langle L \rangle_\infty] < +\infty $ ? (which implies the rest...) Thanks a lot for your help!